# Get created term entity after creating term programatically

Tags: users, 8, taxonomy-terms

I'm writing a custom Drupal Console command to import user data from a text file and create users, and as part of the process, I need to add data to a term reference field. In the case that a term in the data doesn't exist, I need to create the term and then add the new tid to the the field. I'm using the following code to create the term:

```
$term = Term::create([
  'name' => $member[$roster_key],
  'vid' => 'topic_area',
])->save();
```

The problem is the `save()` method only returns a boolean indicating if the save was successful, NOT the created term object. This means that now that my term has been created, I have to go do an entity query just to get the object I just created.

Is there a simple way to get the just-created term in my code above, or do I really have to do a separate query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Term::create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Acreate/8.2.x) returns the entity that the `save()` method gets called on. So what you want to do is save that entity to a var before calling the `save()` method on it.

```
$term = Term::create([
  'name' => $member[$roster_key],
  'vid' => 'topic_area',
]);
$term->save();

//Retrieve the tid of the new term
$term->tid->getValue();
```

Comment: You can get the ID of any entity with $term->id(), much easier. getValue() will also return an array, if anything, you'd want just ->value. See http://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet